# Fetching data using NSXML Parser

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to fetch large amount of data using NSXML Parser, is it possible to execute stored procedures using NSXML Parser.

Answer (score 0):

i have no great experience with NSXML parsing. But i think its better to use CFXML family, it also allows to modify the xml file. I hope it works in ipad platform

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFXML/CFXML.html